# Checking whether the "shifted" random variable is a martingale

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

From Durrett's Stochastic Calculus Chapter 2 Example 1.2, I have found out interesting random variable. Suppose that T is a random variable where $P(T \leq t) = t$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, and there is a independent random variable $\xi$ where $P(\xi = 1) = P(\xi = -1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ (i.e. 1D simple symmetric random walk). Let $X_{t} = 0$ if $t < T$ and $\xi$ if $t \geq T$, and let $F_{t} = \sigma(X_{s}; s \leq t)$ (i.e. natural filtration). From this definition, I am not very sure why it is obvious that $X_{t}$ with filtration $F_{t}$ is a martingale. I tried to find a version of conditional expectation by splitting $X_{t}$ with indicator random variables and use independence or measurability, but it does not work... Can someone help me with this seemingly easy (and stupid) question?

Comment: We need to see what you tried and why exactly it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The integrability of $X_t$ is obvious. For the martingale property, let $s\le t$. On $\{T\le s\}$, $X_t=\xi=X_s$, and on $\{T>t\}$, $X_t=0=X_s$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_t\vert\mathcal F_s]&=\mathbb E[X_t1_{\{T\le s\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[X_t1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[X_t1_{\{t<T\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]\\
&=\mathbb E[X_s1_{\{T\le s\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]+0\\
&=X_s1_{T\notin(s,t]}+\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s].
\end{align}
$$

As $X_s1_{\{s<T\le t\}}=0$, in order to conclude it suffices to show that
$$
\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]=0.
$$

This fact is actually obvious when you notice that the trace of $\mathcal F_s$ on $\{s<T\}$ is trivial and $\xi$ has mean $0$. For example, you can write that $\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]=1_{\{s<T\}}\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]=1_{\{s<T\}}f((X_u)_{u\in[0,s]})=1_{\{s<T\}}f((0)_{u\in[0,s]})=\alpha1_{\{s<T\}}$, where $f$ is some measurable map and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Then by taking the expectation we have
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]]=\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}]=0=\mathbb E[\alpha1_{\{s<T\}}],$$
which shows that either $\alpha=0$ or $T\le s$ almost surely. In either case, $\mathbb E[\xi1_{\{s<T\le t\}}\vert\mathcal F_s]=0$, which proves the claim.

Note that we only used the facts that $\xi$ is integrable with mean $0$ and independent of $T$. In particular, we did not use the specific distribution of $\xi$ nor $T$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, and now I see the idea on how you proceed further from splitting them into the indicators. Can I ask how you could transfrom $\mathbb{E}[\xi1_{T \leq t}|F_{s}]$ to the composite function of $f$ and $X_{u}$ when you manipulated the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\xi1_{s \leq T \leq t}|F_{s}]$? Thanks!

Comment: I used that the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[Y\vert\sigma(X)]$ is almost surely equal to $f(X)$ for some measurable map $f$. Just apply it with $Y=\xi1_{\{T\le t\}}$ and $X=(X_u)_{u\in[0,s]}$.